# COBOL Beginner. Completely lost

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

This is the assignment. I have no clue where to start. I have written some of the code but I am not sure if it is even correct.

[Assignment Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl1wL.png)

Here is what code I have written so far

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. PROGRAM1.
   AUTHOR. KJONES.
  ****************************************************************
  * Program1 produces a TRUCK INVENTORY REPORT listing the current
  * inventory for all three trucks. Listing the truck ID, employee
  * ID, item ID, quantity in stock, purchase price, and selling
  * price.
  * ******
  * INPUT:
  *     The PIZZA FILE contains the following data in
  *     each record:
  *           1. TRUCK ID
  *           2. EMPLOYEE ID
  *           3. DRIVERS FIRST NAME & LAST NAME
  *           4. NUMBER IN STOCK
  *           5. PURCHASE PRICE
  *           6. SELL PRICE
  * ******
  * OUTPUT:
  ****************************************************************
   ENVIROMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   SOURCE-COMPUTER. IBM-PC.
   OBJECT-COMPUTER. IBM-PC.

   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT PIZZA-FILE
           ASSIGN TO 'PIZZA.TXT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT PIZZA-INVENTORY-FILE
           ASSIGN TO PRINTER 'TRUCKINVENTORY'.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.

   FD PIZZA-FILE
      RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS.

   01 PIZZA-RECORD.
       05  PR-TRUCK-ID             PIC X(5).
       05  PR-EMP-ID               PIC X(4).
       05  PR-EMP-NAME             PIC X(20).
       05  PR-ITEM-ID              PIC AA.
       05  PR-NUM-IN-STOCK         PIC S999.
       05  PR-PURCH-PRICE          PIC S999.
       05  PR-SELL-PRICE           PIC S999.
       05  FILLER                  PIC X(40).

   FD PIZZA-INVENTORY-FILE
      RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS.

   01 REPORT-RECORD                PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01  FLAGS-N-SWITCHES.
       05  EOF-FLAG                PIC X         VALUE ' '.

   01  REPORT-FIELDS.
       05  PROPER-SPACING          PIC S9        VALUE +1.

  **************        OUTPUT AREA        ********************

   01 TITLE-ONE.
      05                           PIC X(2)      VALUE SPACES.
      05 H1-DATE                   PIC X(33) 9999/99/99.
      05                           PIC X(32)     VALUE
                                     'ROLLING PIZZA'.
      05                           PIC X(12)     VALUE 'KJJ'.

   01 TITLE-TWO.
      05                           PIC X(33)      VALUE SPACES.
      05                           PIC X(46)      VALUE
                                     'INVENTORY REPORT'.

   01 TITLE-THREE.
      05                           PIC X(5)      VALUE SPACES.
      05                           PIC X(10)     VALUE 'TRUCK'.
      05                           PIC X(13)     VALUE 'EMPLOYEE'.
      05                           PIC X(9)      VALUE 'ITEM'.
      05                           PIC X(11)     VALUE 'NUM IN'.
      05                           PIC X(13)     VALUE 'PURCHASE'.
      05                           PIC X(18)     VALUE 'SELLING'.

   01 TITLE-FOUR.
      05                           PIC X(6)      VALUE SPACES.
      05                           PIC X(12)     VALUE 'ID'.
```

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: You're missing part of your WORKING-STORAGE and PROCEDURE DIVISION.

Answer (score 1):

*This should at least get you started.*

You must fix `H1-DATE` as it is syntactically incorrect.

You must complete the layout of `TITLE-3` to make it match the printer spacing chart.

You must code what are often called "detail lines" holding the data to be printed to match the printer spacing chart.

You will need to code a numeric variable to count the number of lines you have printed.

You must code a `Procedure Division` to...

`Open` your files.

`Read` your input file (this is sometimes called a "priming read") and set your `EOF-FLAG` at end of file.

Probably use a `Perform` statement with the `Until` option to...

- `Write` out new TITLE records `If` this is first time through or a new page is needed; you know a new page is needed by counting how many lines you have printed.  Remember to reinitialize your line counter variable after each new page is printed.
- `Move` data from your input record to your output detail areas.
- `Write` the output detail record.
- `Read` your input file and set your `EOF-FLAG` at end of file.

...the `Until` option must check if your `EOF-FLAG` has been set.

`Close` your files.

`Goback` or `Stop Run`.

So you will probably want to check out the documentation for `Open`, `Close`, `Read`, `Write`, `Perform`, `Move`, `Goback`, and how to increment your line counter variable.  Compilers generally come with this documentation.